Calling the function on the const pointer
Consider the following piece of code:
class Foo
{
publc:
    void Apply();
private:
    const Bar *m_ptr;
};

void Foo::Apply()
{
    m_ptr->ApplyData();
}

class Bar
{
    int ApplyData();
};

I'm getting the following:

error C2662: 'int Bar::ApplyData()': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Bar' to 'Bar &'

What is the problem?
BTW, google gives wrong references on passing the const pointer or using const pointer to the function. So I'm now here.
I can probably const_cast<> the pointer, but it will be wrong.

The dupe is about a reference but it is the same answer for pointers.  The object referred/pointed to is declared const and you cannot call a non-const function on a const object

@NathanOliver, I wish MSVC can make the error message more meaningful ;-) Thx for the answer.

@Igor how much clearer can "cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Bar' to 'Bar &'" get?

Either change const Bar *m_ptr; to Bar *m_ptr;, or change int ApplyData(); to int ApplyData() const; (and make it public:, but that's a different problem).

@Eljay, yes I remove the const from declaration - it's easier than making almost all functions const. However, like I said - I wish the error message would be better worded.

One of the essential features of C++ is const correctness.  Removing const to make it easier for yourself in the short term will make it harder for yourself in the long term.  (Other languages, like Objective-C, use inheritance for that purpose, e.g., NSString (which is immutable) is the base class for NSMutableString (which is mutable, as the name suggests.)
